# Value to assign to 'paramName' parameter for ArgumentException in C# property setter?

Tags: c#, exception, naming-conventions

If an invalid value is passed to a property setter and an `ArgumentException` (or possibility a class derived from it) is thrown, what value should be assigned to the `paramName` parameter?

`value`, since it seemingly is the actual argument?

Wouldn't it be more clear to pass the name of the property instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ArgumentExceptions contain the name of the parameter which is not valid.  For a property setter the actual parameter is named value (in both source and generated code).   It's more consistent to use this name.

Comment: I guess the assumption is that the StackTrace would clarify the property in question.

Answer (score 9):

After extensive poking around with Reflector (trying to find a CLR object with a writable Property), the first one I found (FileStream.Position) using "value" as the argument name:

```
if (value < 0L)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", 
                 Environment.GetResourceString("NeedNonNegNum"));
}
```

Comment: Given CA1507, the exception would rather be the following: `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), ...);` It is funny that you can take a nameof() of a keyword like this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be more clear to pass the name of property.